# Book about an orphan girl with orange curly hair

Tags: story-identification, character-identification, childrens-novel, cover-art

The book cover is dark green with gold details of leafy vines, within the vines are small drawings of things that were in the book like a crow, teddy bear and knife from what I remember

I think in the middle of the front cover was the girl with orange curly hair.

Comment: Were there any science fiction or fantasy elements in this book? If there were, please edit the question to specify them.

Comment: "an orphan girl with orange curly hair"  Did her eyes have pupils?

Comment: If it is Little Orphan Annie, there should be enough "fantastic elements" to satisfy the topic police.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [Anne of Green Gables](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8127.Anne_of_Green_Gables)? I've found a few book covers that match, such as this one:

[image]

You can search through other editions [here](https://www.goodreads.com/work/editions/3464264).

Of course, if it is Anne of Green Gables, the question is off topic for lack of sci-fi/fantasy/

Comment: It could be my weak eyes but I can't find the crow or the teddy bear or the knife.